# CakePHP - SQL query Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Ok, so i'm in a pickle trying to figure a way for how to do this :

I have a live search(using ajax) which allows the user to select a criteria from a dropdown list and then enter a value which will be matched to values inside the database. This is quite trivial stuff, and on direct fields of the main model, i don't have any issues.

I have a Donor Model/table which consists of attributes such as `ID, Name, Surname etc`, but more importantly it also has `FK` of other associated models such as `blood_group_id, donor_type_id,` which map back to the respective models (`BloodGroup and DonorType`).. These two are already set with the associations and I am beyond that part, as I am already retrieving Donor records with associated model data.

Here is the search method which will hopefully help you in understanding my problem better.

```
public function search() {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if(!empty($this->request->data)){
                $criteria = $this->request->data['criteria'];
                $query = $this->request->data['query'];
                $conditions = array("Donor." .$criteria. " LIKE '". $query . "%'");
```

The above checks if its a post request and whether data was sent. The criteria and user input are used to construct the query..

This is where my problem arises.. (When the user select search By blood type, as a criteria from the drop down)the above expects the user to enter the id of the blood_group rather than A+ or A- for instance.. So if the input is 1(id of blood group A+), the results are returned as expected. But I want the user to be able to enter A+...

Here is the rest of the method :

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'limit' => 2
            );


 $donors = $this->Paginator->paginate('Donor');
            $this->set('donors', $donors);
            $this->beforeRender();
            $this->layout= 'ajax';
        } 
    }
}
```

I have tried this approach, setting up the conditions using the Model's name such as

```
   if($criteria == 'blood_group_id'){
       $conditions = array("BloodGroup.id" . " LIKE '". $query . "%'");
   }elseif($criteria == 'donor_type_id'){
       $conditions = array("DonorType.id" . " LIKE '". $query . "%'");
   }else{
       $this->Paginator->settings = array(
          'conditions' => $conditions,
          'limit' => 2
       );
   }
```

But this returns all the records irrespective of the input.

I also tried changing the settings for the paginator with no luck

```
$settings = array(
  'joins' => array(
     'table' => 'blood_groups',
     'alias' => 'BloodGroup',
     'type' => 'LEFT',
     'conditions' => array(
        "BloodGroup.id" => "Donor.blood_group_id",
        "AND" => $conditions
     )
   ),
'limit'=> 2
);
```

Any help on how to accomplish what I explained above, would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: how do you populate your criteria dropwodn list?

Comment: @arilia it is hardcoded like so :` 'options' => array(
                            'id'=> 'By ID',
                            'name' => 'By Name',
                            'blood_group_id' => 'By Blood Type',
                            'type' => 'By Donor Type',
                            'age' => 'By Age',
                            'gender' => 'By Gender' 
                        )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply:

```
if($criteria == 'blood_group_id')
    $conditions = array("BloodGroup.name LIKE" => $query.'%');
```

(assuming bood_types has a 'name' column)

Also let me suggest you to use the CakeDC search plugin (https://github.com/CakeDC/search).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the plugin :) though the query still returns all records and not filtered..

Comment: because your `if` is wrong and PHP never enters the Paginator->settings code block if $criteria == 'block_group_id'. Try and rewrite the whole if logic

Comment: OOPS- Ofcourse!! how did I miss that! I feel so stupid and ignorant now, my bad!! Thank you for all your help !! - lesson learned- inspect all code especially the most trivial. sometimes I overlook  these SILLY mistakes

Comment: Arilia, can you please point me to a good tutorial which can get me started on cakeDC search. so far, I can't quite seem to understand how it works, and without insulting the developers who created cakeDC search, the documentation seems to lack the correct grammar to a point which I do not understand it, apart from being very brief. I have watched this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAVuLXFVaCw), which is better than nothing, but still not quite there yet.

Comment: maybe the best way is that you try some code yourself and when you are stuck you post another question here on SO providing the code you'll have tried so far

Comment: ok, I posted a question regarding this if you can help, i'd greatly appreciate it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682882/cakephp-cakedc-search-plugin-implementation